# In a Spotfire bar chart, I want to compare actuals to Budget, after a certain month I want the Actuals to change color when it becomes Forecast

Tags: bar-chart, spotfire

I have this bar chart which shows Actuals (orange) and Budget (blue). Is there a way to change the colors of the bars for months 7-12 to a different color?
[bar chart image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LYzwJ.png)

I already tried adding the "Type" column to the color, this results in the following, which is not acceptable because of the wasted space which is impossible to remove.
[unacceptable workaround](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cZfkL.png)

Does anyone have a solution for this, to either change the colors in the bars in the top image, or remove the wasted space in the bottom image?

Thanks in advance!

Edit: I cannot embed the images because don't have enough reputation :(